# generar multiples inserts spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Tengo una aplicación spring boot, donde en la vista tengo una lista de animales(ganado), los que puedo seleccionar con checkbox al estilo del correo Gmail  cuando se quieren eliminar. Luego con un botón los asigno a un lote, lo que debe generar un insert en la base de datos por cada animal seleccionado.
La llamada al controlador la hago mediante jquery ajax.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lote_animales")
public class LoteAnimal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idloteanimales")
    private long idLoteAnimal;
    
    @Column(name = "idlote")
    private int idLote;
    
    @Column(name = "idanimal")
    private int diio;
    
    @Column(name = "vigente")
    private int vigente;
    
    @Column(name = "id_establecimiento")
    private int idEstablecimiento;
    
    @Column(name = "fecha_accion")
    private Date fechaAccion;
```

SERVICE:

```
public interface LoteAnimalService {

    public abstract LoteAnimal addLoteAnimal(LoteAnimal loteAnimal);
}
```

IMPL

```
@Service
public class LoteAnimalServiceImpl implements LoteAnimalService {

    @Autowired
    public LoteAnimalRepository repository;

    @Override
    public LoteAnimal addLoteAnimal(LoteAnimal loteAnimal) {
        return repository.save(loteAnimal);
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@PostMapping("/add-animal-lote")
public ResponseEntity<?> addAnimalLote(@RequestBody LoteAnimal loteAnimal){
    loteAnimalService.addLoteAnimal(loteAnimal);
    return new ResponseEntity<LoteAnimal>(loteAnimal,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Este metodo post se ejecuta bien 1 vez por cada animal, pero quiero que se ejecute N veces por cada animal seleccionado en la lista de la vista.

Alguna idea por favor de como puede hacer esto?

Comment: Quieres es insertar una lista con todos los checkboxs que seleccionaste?

Comment: exacto, un insert por cada ID seleccionado con los check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por que no mejor utilizas el método `saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);` del CrudRepository, podría ayudarte pasando una lista de LoteAnimal de una sola vez en tu request, en lugar de generar múltiples peticiones a tu servicio